# Datetime subtraction raises unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' error

Tags: python, dataset

I want to do subtraction between both `closed date` and `created date` column and have the result formatted as `datetime` itself.
This is my code:

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe = pd.read_csv('311_Service_Requests_from_2010_to_Present.csv') #import of dataset

dataframe['Request_Closing_Time']= dataframe['Closed Date'].values-dataframe['Created Date'].values

print(dataframe['Request_Closing_Time'])
```

It raises this kind of error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

This is an example of the kind of datetime format contained on both columns:

```
12/31/2015 11:59:45 PM
```